# Best way to send javascript variables to ERB in rails using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know you can use ajax, but I cant figure out how... It's really frustrating. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/home/index',
  data: {params1: "", params2: ""},
  success: function(response) {
    // code to be executed
  }
});
```

In rails HomeController index action

you can get your parameters , then by assigning those params to an instance varible, you can get those values in your ERB file

Comment: Thanks! What are the data params though? Sorry, Im new to ajax :P